# Questions around mean comparisons between groups

Tags: t-test, paired-data

I'm trying to understand the process of comparing groups and I have a number of questions with Google searches giving me more questions. And unfortunately I'm a person that can't move forward without understanding the why.

Context setting / example: I have a situation where a group of people came to a store (600K) and 200K didn't come back but 400K did come back, and I wanted to see the difference in the means of their behavior to understand why the 200K didn't return.

I wanted to run several t-test on several variables given the unequal sample sizes between the two groups. I wanted to see if there are any differences in their means for each of these variables to see if there are any indicators why one person might have left, but the other came back. Variables are items like (did they respond to an email, age, income etc) But I have a number of questions:

- I have a few binary variables (yes/no), since these variables don't have a continuous distribution, how can I compare if the difference is significant between the two groups?
- I know there are different types of t-tests, but struggling to find the best one. Would this be considered comparing two groups from the same population? My old understanding is that t tests were used to compare small sample sizes, is this still small? How is small enough defined for a t-test?
- I've noticed quite a few discussions on power analysis, my understanding is this measures the effect actually occurring when we said it would. Should I be factoring that in when doing a comparison of mean? Is that a necessary aspect of this process? Why is it or why is it not?
- I would be running this test to understand the differences of means on several variables, is this the best approach to run several comparison tests on several variables?
- This is a simple analysis for now, but I'd be curious to know how do you know when to factor in influencing variables? What is your approach? Ie when should I consider holding their income constant and then comparing the difference in the mean? How would I know that not doing this isn't rendering my analysis useless?